How to add a footnote to diagrammeR
In this flow chart I want to add a footnote:
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph {
graph [layout = dot]
node [shape = box]
a [label = 'hi']
b [label = 'there']
a -> {b}

}

")


Expected result:
The footnote should appear in the right bottom corner:


One possible option would be to wrap the flowchart and the footnote in a div, e.g. in an Rmd or quarto document or a shiny app you could user something like htmltools::div(grViz(...), htmltools::p("footnote", align = "right", style="color: red;"))

@stefan. Thank you. I use these 3 steps to apply your solution for my needs:
`# 1.
output <- htmltools::div(
graph,
htmltools::p("footnote", align = "right", style="color: red;")
)
2.
htmltools::save_html(output, "output.html")
3.
webshot2::webshot("output.html", file = "output.png")` Quite cumbersome for a relatively simple task?
